# How to compile Mapbox Android Events Repository Project? Unauthorized response for sdk-registry

Tags: android-studio, mapbox, mapbox-android

Based on an critical API change by android API Level 31 (refer to this thread [click here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-events-android/issues/578)) we need to fix some lines in libtelemetry/libcore of the following repository:
https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-events-android.
Therefore we want to compile the project by ourself as the repo does not seem to be maintained at all.

We downloaded the whole project and trying to compile in Android Studio. But we can't get rid of this error:

> Could not GET 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/gradle/plugins/sdk-registry/0.4.0/sdk-registry-0.4.0.pom'.
> Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

What we have already tried:

- Added a new private download token in our mapbox-account
- Added the following lines to the settings.xml based on this documentation ([navigation-sdk for android docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/guides/get-started/install/))

  ```
    dependencyResolutionManagement {
        repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
                authentication {
                    basic(BasicAuthentication)
                }
                credentials {
                    // Do not change the username below.
                    // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
                    username = "mapbox"
                    // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
                    password = "OUR_PRIVATE_TOKEN"
                }
            }
        }
    }
  ```

any ideas what we are missing to compile the project correctly? oO

thanks in advance!